# How to quote colons in graph query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have some code which gets details of lists in a SharePoint site then later wants to find out if a list with the same name still exists. This works fine except for list names that contain a colon - I find Graph misinterprets the colon and 'corrupts' the URL.

For instance, in Graph Explorer when I give it the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites('mysite.sharepoint.com,aa-aa-aa,bb-bb-bb')/lists('19:abcdef@thread.tacv2_wiki')
```

The error response contains the following in the 'message' property:

```
The expression \"sites('mysite.sharepoint.com,aa-aa-aa,bb-bb-bb')/lists('19')/abcdef@thread.tacv2_wiki\" is not valid.
```

Note that it's split the original URL, thinking the colon is the start of a new segment in the path, even though it's inside a quote.

I've tried all sorts of quoting of the colon (%3A and %253A and %25253A) and different styles of quote characters, but they all either return the same error or give a parsing error.

More information - I specifically want to search by name not by original id (which would be much easier), I'm acutually using Graph Managed API in code but it generates the same error (you'd think it would internally know how to quote), the list is actually a hidden one created in a Teams site to manage channel information.

Comment: You can use **Filter Query Parameter**  as shown below and get the list.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/lists?$filter=displayName eq '19:abcdef@thread.tacv2_wiki'

Comment: That's a great answer, but I couldn't get it to work for lists. Looking at this page to check the syntax:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

Even the supplied example of `?$filter=startswith(displayName,'J')` (which is written for Users) fails on the Lists endpoint, and all other formats I've tried fail, such as `/lists?$filter=eq(displayName,'1')` or `/lists?$filter='19:abcdef@thread.tacv2_wiki'` give an 'Invalid filter clause' error :-(

Comment: I have tested it with Graph Explorer setting up your scenario and the below query worked for me. Please use it this way how I give and see if it can help, just modify siteid. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/lists?$filter=displayName eq '19:abcdef@thread.tacv2_wiki'`

Comment: Please let me know if it worked or not Richard.:)-

Comment: Thanks, that syntax did the trick! Bit odd that syntax isn't on the MS page about filter.

FYI  perhaps that format was on your original link but the spaces meant the link that appears in StackOverflow only runs up to the first space, so I lost your intended syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the Confirmation Richard. Glad to here that.:)-

Comment: Hi , if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also able to reproduce your issue but as a work around you can use the filter query parameter to get the list by using below query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/lists?$filter=displayName eq '19:abcdef@thread.tacv2_wiki'
```

[image]