# Graph filter for a SharePoint list using 'displayName eq' quoting all characters

Tags: c#, sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the C# `Microsoft.Graph` API to talk to Microsoft Graph to find out if a specific list exists in a SharePoint Online site. I want this to be robust against all problematic characters in the list name, and use of `GraphServiceClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listName]` fails if the `listName` has a colon in it, so (after advice from StackOverflow) I switched to using a filter.

I've tried all sorts of encoding of problematic characters and can't get it to consistently work - it either returns an error `The expression ... is not valid` or says that the list does not exist when it does.

Here's one variation of my code:

```
var name="lis !\"£$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':@#~/.,?><`¬";
var encodedName=System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name);
existingListRequest.QueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("filter", $"displayName eq '{encodedName}'"));
```

The above fails but the error quotes the original 'name' without any encoding, so expect the encoding is being decoded before it gets to the filter. I've tried without using `UrlEncode`, and using it twice, and using it then replacing all the '%' characters in the result with '%25' but none will successfully find the list.

What's the definitive way to encode problem characters in a Graph filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I worked out the right solution:

name.Replace("'", "''").Replace("#", "%23").Replace("&", "%26").Replace("+", "%2b");

All those steps were included in previous trials but I think perhaps something else I then encoded made it fail to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to replace colon with *x003a* in list name. Hope this will sort your issue.

string listName = ListName.Replace(':', '*x003a*');

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Colon is not the issue - I raised the issue of having colon in the name when not using a filter in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63844789/how-to-quote-colons-in-graph-query  There I covered that I'd tried all sorts of encoding of the colon which didn't work, and using a filter seemed the best answer, however other characters need handling, which lead to this question.

Comment: FYI I don't think your suggestion is right anyway, that would need to be something like '%3a' - what you've written starts with an 'x' and an 'x' is a legitimate normal character for a list name.

Comment: _ needs to follow at start and end of ‘x003a’

Comment: This works in the list column selection. %3a could be used in list name. While in case both not worked. You can use filter query to find the list